# Send FileList in FormData in javascrirpt

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, form-data, filelist

I am trying to send a bunch of images using FormData but of course, I cannot send FileList and I was unsuccessful in figuring out a way to send these files. I have already tried to find answers on my own but most of them suggest appending each file.

```js
for (let i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
    formData.append("images[]", images[i]);
}
```

But it ends up with only the last file inside formData, for some reason previous files are being replaced by the next one in line.

I have also tried to convert FileList to an array, which works but I don't know how I could separate these files, right now every file is inside one key as a string.

```json
0: "[{\"lastModified\":1606255989000,\"lastModifiedDate\":\"undefined\",\"name\":\"logo.png\",\"size\":54438,\"type\":\"image/png\"},{\"lastModified\":1606255979000,\"lastModifiedDate\":\"undefined\",\"name\":\"logo1.png\",\"size\":58023,\"type\":\"image/png\"},{\"lastModified\":1606252752000,\"lastModifiedDate\":\"undefined\",\"name\":\"logo2.png\",\"size\":28147,\"type\":\"image/png\"},{\"lastModified\":1606255121000,\"lastModifiedDate\":\"undefined\",\"name\":\"logo3.png\",\"size\":18260,\"type\":\"image/png\"}]"
```

I could just convert it to string and cut it to their own keys using `}` as and end of each entry. I don't want to do this, even with my little experience I know it's not a good way to go about it.

As of this moment, my javascript code looks like this.

```js
 File.prototype.toObject = function () {
  return Object({
    lastModified: parseInt(this.lastModified),
    lastModifiedDate: String(this.lastModifiedDate),
    name: String(this.name),
    size: parseInt(this.size),
    type: String(this.type)
    })
  }

  FileList.prototype.toArray = function () {
    return Array.from(this).map(function (file) {
      return file.toObject()
    })
  }

  let files = document.getElementById('files').files

  let filesArray = files.toArray();

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('images[]', JSON.stringify(filesArray));
```

I then send this data like this

```js
fetch('<?=env('app.baseURL')?>/admin/gallery', {
      method: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      headers: {
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      },
      body: formData,
      data: formData,
      }).then(function (response) {...rest of the code...})
```

After sending this data, which is received without any problems I want to save these files, but I cannot without first separating them. I am using PHP for the back-end.

I don't have much experience with javascript so I might be missing something obvious, any help is appreciated.

Comment: "but I cannot without first separating them" what does this mean? 
You could simply run through them with a for loop.

Comment: no because they are saved as one value so I would have to just cut it like string, I don't think it's the best way to go about it

Comment: Your "images[]" sends an array to PHP. You just have to use a loop to go through it as $_FILES['images']['name'][0], $_FILES['images']['name'][1], etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you could use dynamic name for your formData appends. For example:

```
formData.append(`image-${i}`, images[i])
```

Or in case you want to push your images to a single key value pair in your formData, like in your example, you should use the getAll() method to retrieve your images.

```
formData.getAll('images[]')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out, seems I thought the issue was something different and I was just pestering E-telier about it but from what I see after he linked me an explanation of what I should do to achieve what I wanted here, your answer was exactly what I needed. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the PHP code to go through the array containing the images :

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['images'])){
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
        $filename = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO myimages (filename) VALUES ('".$filename."')";
        $db->query($sql);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. It seems that in my case $_FILES is empty. I can confirm that data gets through and like you said in a comment it is an array, after using json_decode it nicely puts everything back together.

Unfortunately, I can't upload files with just an array of objects, at least I don't know how. I am using CodeIgniter 4 as a php framework if it helps.

Comment: I don't know CodeIgniter, the code I wrote is vanilla PHP. The actual files are copied on the server with move_uploaded_file(). If $_FILES is empty it's probably due to CodeIgniter using another method. I found this article about it : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: This is a library from an older version of CodeIgniter but in the current version, it handles uploaded files the same way that $_FILES does but it's just much simpler to work with these files. The issue right now is that it seems that there are no valid files, could it be because it's being retrieved as Objects and not Files?

Comment: Files need to be sent as form input files indeed. Here is a good explanation about it : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/formdata-explained/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally got it working, you're awesome!